# I can't figure out what the error is here. It says it's in line 3 and 46

Tags: c

I have very little knowledge to coding and I cannot find what is wrong with with I have here. I think I mostly did everything right but like I said, I do not know how to code well. This is the question "Your task is to create a function that does four basic mathematical operations.

The function should take three arguments - operation(string/char), value1(number), value2(number).
The function should return result of numbers after applying the chosen operation."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int basic_op(char op, int value1, int value2){  
    printf("Enter first number \n");        
    scanf("%d", &value1);               
    printf("First number is %d \n", value1); 
    
    printf("Enter function, + , - , * , / \n"); 
    scanf("%s", &op);                               
    printf("Function is %s \n", &op);                           
    
    printf("Enter second number \n");       
    scanf("%d", &value2);
    printf("Second number is %d \n", value2);       

  
    if (op == '+')
    {
        float sum;
        sum = value1 + value2;
        printf("The sum is %f \n", sum);
    }
    else if (op == '-')
    {
        float difference;
        difference = value1 - value2;
        printf("The difference is %f \n", difference);
    }
    else if (op == '*')
    {
        float product;
        product = value1 * value2;
        printf("The product is %f \n", product);
    }
    else if (op == '/')
    {
        float quotient;
        while (value2 == 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter a number\n");
            printf("Please enter a non-zero number\n");
            scanf("%d", &value2);
        }
        quotient = value1 / value2;
        printf("The product is %f \n", quotient);
}
  }

int main(){
  int basic_op(char op, int value1, int value2);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Normally if your compiler tells you something is wrong, it includes an error message with a description what is wrong and where it thinks something is wrong. You should carefully read that message. And you should show us that messages if you are asking for help about that exact error.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with warnings, i.e: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o demo demo.c` you get:

```
demo.c: In function ‘basic_op’:
demo.c:48:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   48 |   }
      |   ^
```

That is, you promised to return an `int` from the function but you have not done so.

On the other hand, are you aware that your program is not calling the function?

```
int main(){
  int basic_op(char op, int value1, int value2);
}
```

should be shomething like

```
int main(void){ // Use a valid prototype for main
  int result = basic_op('-', 3, 2);

  printf("%d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Also:

```
printf("Enter function, + , - , * , / \n"); 
scanf("%s", &op);                             
printf("Function is %s \n", &op);
```

A `char` wants `%c` as format specifier, not `%s`, but why are you asking the user to introduce the numbers and an operator? They are already provided by the caller, use the arguments `op`, `value1` and `value2`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h> You don't need it

int basic_op(char op, int value1, int value2)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("The sum is: ");
            return value1 + value2;
        case '-':
            printf("The difference is: ");
            return value1 - value2;
        case '*':
            printf("The product is: ");
            return value1 * value2;
        case '/':
            printf("The division is: ");
            return value1 / value2;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int result = basic_op('-', 3, 2);

    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h> You don't need it

int basic_op(void)
{
    int value1 = 0, value2 = 0;
    char op = 0;

    printf("Enter first number\n");        
    scanf("%d", &value1);               
    printf("First number is %d\n", value1); 
    
    printf("Enter function, + , - , * , /\n"); 
    scanf(" %c", &op); // Notice a space before %c                           
    printf("Function is %s \n", &op);                           
    
    printf("Enter second number\n");       
    scanf("%d", &value2);
    printf("Second number is %d\n", value2);

    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("The sum is: ");
            return value1 + value2;
        case '-':
            printf("The difference is: ");
            return value1 - value2;
        case '*':
            printf("The product is: ");
            return value1 * value2;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int result = basic_op();

    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```